# Filter search and pjax not working in yii2 gridview

Tags: gridview

I used the CRUD generator in Yii2 to generate codes, I want to make sorting, filter search and pjax working on the gridview, sorting is working perfectly, but filter search and pjax not working.. below is my code..
controller..  actionIndex

```
$searchModel = new ProductSearch();
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
     'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
```

my view file index.php

```
<?php echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>


<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
   'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'pager' => [
    'firstPageLabel' => 'first',
    'lastPageLabel' => 'last',
    'prevPageLabel' => '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>',
    'nextPageLabel' => '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>',
    'maxButtonCount' => 5,

    // Customzing CSS class for navigating link
    'prevPageCssClass' => 'mypre',
    'nextPageCssClass' => 'mynext',
    'firstPageCssClass' => 'myfirst',
    'lastPageCssClass' => 'mylast',


],


    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

       // 'product_id',
        'type_name',
        'name',
        'descr',
        'price',
        [
         'attribute'=>'image',
        'label'=>'Image',
        'format'=>'html',
        'value' => function ($data) {
                $url = $data['image'];
                $alt = $data['name'];
                return Html::img($url, ['alt'=>$alt,'title'=>$alt,'width'=>'70','height'=>'50' ]);
         }
       ],
        // 'added_at','
        // 'updated_at',
        'views',
       'status',
        // 'reviews',


        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
    'tableOptions' =>['class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered'],
]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

if i render _search.php file in my index page as in below code the search is working but not working in filtersearch

```
<?php echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>
```

below is my search models

```
 public function search($params)
{
    $query = Products::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination'=> ['defaultPageSize' => 5],
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'product_id' => $this->product_id,
        'type_id' => $this->type_id,
        'status' => $this->status,
        'price' => $this->price,
        'added_at' => $this->added_at,
        'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        'views' => $this->views,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'type_name', $this->type_name])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'descr', $this->descr])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'image', $this->image])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'reviews', $this->reviews]);

    return $dataProvider;
```

Any help on how to make the filtersearch work and also make pjax work correcly.. thanks

Comment: Did you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911457/yii2-pjax-not-working